# C# Template parsing and matching with text file

Tags: c#, templates

Need some ideas how to solve this problem.
I have a template file what describes the line in the text file. For example:

Template

```
[%f1%]|[%f2%]|[%f3%]"[%f4%]"[%f5%]"[%f6%]
```

Text file

```
1234|1234567|123"12345"12"123456
```

Now i need to read in the fields from the text file. In the template file fields are described with `[%some name%]`. Allso in the template file there is set what the field separators are, in this example here there are `|` and `"`. The  lenght of the fields can change through different files but the separators will stay the same. What would be the best way to read in the template and by template read in the text file?

EDIT: Text file has multiple rows, like this:

```
1234|1234567|123"12345"12"123456"\r\n
1234|field|123"12345"12"asdasd"\r\n
123sd|1234567|123"asdsadf"12"123456"\r\n
45gg|somedata|123"12345"12"somefield"\r\n
```

EDIT2: Ok, lets make it even harder. Some fields can contain binary data and i know the starting and end position of the binary data field. I should be able to mark those fields in the template and then the parser will know that this field is binary. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Did the fields values are decimal digits only?

Comment: @HalfTrackMindMan: no, field values can be anything, sometimes even in binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a regex based on the template and then parse the text file using that:

```
class Parser
{
    private static readonly Regex TemplateRegex =
        new Regex(@"\[%(?<field>[^]]+)%\](?<delim>[^[]+)?");

    readonly List<string> m_fields = new List<string>();
    private readonly Regex m_textRegex;

    public Parser(string template)
    {
        var textRegexString = '^' + TemplateRegex.Replace(template, Evaluator) + '$';
        m_textRegex = new Regex(textRegexString);
    }

    string Evaluator(Match match)
    {
        // add field name to collection and create regex for the field
        var fieldName = match.Groups["field"].Value;
        m_fields.Add(fieldName);
        string result = "(.*?)";

        // add delimiter to the regex, if it exists
        // TODO: check, that only last field doesn't have delimiter
        var delimGroup = match.Groups["delim"];
        if (delimGroup.Success)
        {
            string delim = delimGroup.Value;
            result += Regex.Escape(delim);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public IDictionary<string, string> Parse(string text)
    {
        var match = m_textRegex.Match(text);
        var groups = match.Groups;

        var result = new Dictionary<string, string>(m_fields.Count);

        for (int i = 0; i < m_fields.Count; i++)
            result.Add(m_fields[i], groups[i + 1].Value);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats a really good idea, but im not so sure if it would suite me.

Comment: @svick, what i meant was that i have try to fit in and then i can tell if it will suite me or not. But i think its the best idea yet.

Comment: @svick, how would u changed the logic if i would of told in the beginning that in the text file there are multiple rows? I added a new example with multiple rows to the original post.

Comment: @hs2d, I wouldn't change that, but I would call it like `File.ReadAllLines(path).Select(parser.Parse)`. That expressions returns a sequence of dictionaries, with one dictionary for each line.

Comment: @svick, im sorry but i cant see how this could work? Maybe u can explain it to me? Because how i see it is that parser.Parse expects a string of one line but in the example in the comment you are not giving it anything?

Comment: @hs2d, in the example I am giving it one line at a time, that's how `Select()` works. Another way to write the same code would be `File.ReadAllLines(path).Select(line => parser.Parse(line))`.

Comment: @svick, ah, ok. didnt know `Select()` works like that also. Did u tested it yourself with multiple lines? When i use this approach with Select then i get the sequence back but all the values are empty.

Comment: @hs2d, yeah I did, and it worked fine on your sample multiline data (except for the final `"`, which isn't in your template).

Comment: @svick, i figured out what the problem was. `ReadAllLine()` removes the line brake (\r\n) from the end of the one line. But i had it in my template. I need to check for the end of one line because for example when field holds a binary data then it can be on multiple lines allso and then i need to check that there always is somekind of end of line characters. On my example here in original question i didnt show them, so maybe i should change it a little.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the template using regular expressions. An expression like this will match each field definition and separator:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(template, @"^(\[%(?<name>.+?)%\](?<separator>.)?)+$")
```

The match will contain two named groups for (name and separator), each of which will contain a number of captures for each time they matched in the input string. In your example, the separator group would have one less capture than the name group.

You can then iterate over the captures, and use the results to extract the fields from the input string and store the values, like this:

```
if( m.Success )
{
    Group name = m.Groups["name"];
    Group separator = m.Groups["separator"];
    int index = 0;
    Dictionary<string, string> fields = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    for( int x = 0; x < name.Captures.Count; ++x )
    {
        int separatorIndex = input.Length;
        if( x < separator.Captures.Count )
            separatorIndex = input.IndexOf(separator.Captures[x].Value, index);
        fields.Add(name.Captures[x].Value, input.Substring(index, separatorIndex - index));
        index = separatorIndex + 1;
    }
    // Do something with results.
}
```

Obviously in a real program you'd have to account for invalid input and such, which I didn't do here.

Comment: Im not so good at using regex but did you tried if that regex should work?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a few lines of code. Loop through your template row, grabbing all text between "[" as the variable name and everything else as a terminator. Read all the text to the terminal, assign it to the variable name, repeat.

Answer (score 0):

1- Use API for that `sscanf(line, format, __arglist)` check [here](http://www.debugging.com/bug/17570)

2- Use string split Like:

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetDataFromLines(string[] lines)
{ 
    //handle the output data
    List<int> data = new List<int>();

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        string[] seperators = new string[] { "|", "\"" };

        string[] results = line.Split(seperators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        foreach (string result in results)
        {
            data.Add(int.Parse(result));
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

Test it with line:

```
line = "1234|1234567|123\"12345\"12\"123456";
string[] lines = new string[] { line };

GetDataFromLines(lines);

//output list items are:
1234
1234567
123
12345
12
123456
```

Comment: @hs2d: did you try the string.Split like the example above?

Comment: This wont work for me because after parsing the text file i need to know in what order the fields were and what separator they had between them.