# StreamReader and binary data

Tags: c#, .net, binary-data, streamreader

I have this text file what contains different fields. Some fields may contain binary data. I need to get all the data in the file but right now when using StreamReader then it wont read the binary data block and data what comes after that. What would be the best solution to solve this problem?

Example:

```
field1|field2|some binary data here|field3
```

Right now i read in the file like this:

```
public static string _fileToBuffer(string Filename)
{
    if (!File.Exists(Filename)) throw new ArgumentNullException(Filename, "Template file does not exist");

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Filename, Encoding.Default, true);
    string fileBuffer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();

    return fileBuffer;
}
```

EDIT: I know the start and end positions of the binary fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`StreamReader` isn't designed for binary data. It's designed for *text* data, which is why it extends `TextReader`. To read binary data, you should use a `Stream`, and not try to put the results into a string (which is, again, for text data).

In general, it's a bad idea to mix binary data and text data in a file like this - what happens if the binary data includes the | symbol for example? You might want to include the binary data in some text-encoded form, such as a base64 variant avoiding |.

Comment: @hs2d: So what *does* happen if the binary data includes the ASCII (or whatever encoding is used) representation for `|`? Is there anything in the first two fields which tells you the expected length?

Comment: there is nothing what tells me the expected lenght. Look at my other question. Im using template to get the field separators what mark the end of one field: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479505/c-template-parsing-and-matching-with-text-file)

Comment: ok, got some more information. The binary field is always with the same lenght and i know the start and end positions. I update my original question.

Answer (score 9):

use [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx)

Comment: And BinaryWriter to write the file in a reasonable binary format.

Comment: When i use BinaryReader then il get all the fields in binary, so where should i go from there to get back the fields that are not binary data as strings?

Comment: @hs2d StringBuilder + BinaryReader.ReadChar but if you can change the source file, use ReadString.

Comment: @Guillaume, changing the source file isnt possible.