# A templating engine which supports generating a parser from a template

Tags: python, parsing, templates, django-templates, template-engine

I am trying to make my templating engine for Python work backwards. That is, not only generate a document given a template and data, but also extract the data given a template and a document.

Given the page

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/polls/456/">What is your name, stranger?</a></li>
</ul>
```

and the template

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

it will return a `latest_question_list` containing that one item.

What tool do you use to do this? It does not have to support Django templates, other templating engines will do just fine.

Comment: Very interesting, this is going  to require a lot of planning. You are going to have to make sure that the data structure is the same for each page, or that you have some configuration file to know what types of data are on the page and what exactly that data that you are getting really is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479505/c-sharp-template-parsing-and-matching-with-text-file

Comment: textfsm semistructured text parser https://code.google.com/p/textfsm/wiki/TextFSMHowto

Answer (score 1):

This breakthrough happened already. This is called bidirectional or invertible parsing. See it discussed here https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16392654

And this paper https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/1863523.1863525 "Invertible syntax descriptions: unifying parsing and pretty printing"

And this Haskell library https://hackage.haskell.org/package/roundtrip among others

source: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=25319810